# Grabbing a body class element and turning it into a PHP variable

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, media-queries, responsive-design

I am theming a new site using Responsive Design techniques and mostly using CSS Media Queries and this has worked really well. However in some cases I need to get the width of the browser and I do that by adding an `<html>` class with this nifty bit fo JQuery:

```
    (function($) {
        //add drupal 7 specific code
        Drupal.behaviors.getWidthTheme = {
            attach: function(context, settings) {
                //end drupal calls

var w, html = $('html'), _window = $(window);
 _window.resize(onResize);
function onResize() {
w = _window.width();
if (w >= 310 && w < 480 )  html.addClass('mobile-320').removeClass('mobile-768').removeClass('desktop').removeClass('mobile-480');
else if (w >= 481 && w < 768 )  html.addClass('mobile-480').removeClass('mobile-768').removeClass('desktop').removeClass('mobile-320');
else if ( w >= 768 && w < 960 ) html.addClass('mobile-768').removeClass('mobile-480').removeClass('desktop').removeClass('mobile-320');
else html.addClass('desktop').removeClass('mobile-480').removeClass('mobile-768').removeClass('mobile-320');
                }
onResize();

            }}})(jQuery);
```

The code above injects a class into the `<html>` element, e.g. `<html class="mobile-320">` etc... depending on the width of the browser or device.

What I'd like to do is grab that class and somehow convert it into a PHP variable so I can switch off some code. Ideally it would be something like this:

```
<?php if ($mobile-320): ?>
<!--do something-->
<?php else : ?>

<?php if ($mobile-480 || $mobile-768 || $desktop): ?>
<!-- do some other thing -->
<?php endif;  ?>
```

Ideally these classes are grabbed from the HTML class that's been rendered. However, I am not sure this can work as PHP needs to render on the server whereas I am injecting the HTML class via JQuery. I am basically open to any way of doing this, not set on what I have above but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: I don't think you're going to find a simple fix for this, other than using maybe ajax to call this code once the page has loaded, or by having a landing page that has a cookie set with the JS and then forwards to the site afterwards. What's the code doing that you want to avoid running?

Comment: @BenGriffiths - I have php blocks with code within the if - else where if it's one width, I want to show one block but if it's all other widths, I want to show another block.  Of course I could use my existing class to simply do a `display:none` for one block or another but the problem with that is all the code still needs to load and I am trying to make this lightweight for mobile. I think you are correct though, this will not be simple.

Comment: Don't forget that PHP is server side, so unless your web app is slow, then it shouldn't make much difference in speed to the end user be they a mobile client or desktop. If it's really that much of an issue I'd be thinking of making a dedicated mobile site rather than trying a responsive approach.

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure I understand, but maybe you can set off another ajax request, sending the name of the class you just inserted. the response of the php could be json-data to control what you need to execute next, or it could be html/javascript directly. it would help to see more of your html/javascript.

```
$.getJSON('getDeviceActions.php',
  { className: $('html').attr('class') }, 
  function(phpResult){
     if( phpResult.switchOffA == true ) $('.divsel').hide(); //or what not
  }
});
```

Why cant you do your switch-statement directly in javascript, without asking the server, and what is it going to do with the information afterwards?

Comment: mindandmedia - I can't do the switch with Javascript because there is dynamic PHP that needs to be executed within the if-else. The more I think about this, the more I think I have taken the wrong approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can put all classes in an array and pass that array in `data`:

```
var classes = $('html').attr('class').match(/\w+/g);
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'url.php',
    data: {
        classes: classes
    }
    success: function() {
        // Blabla
    }
});
```

Btw, your first piece of code can be reduced if you only have those classes in `$('html')`:

```
if (w >= 310 && w < 480 ) { html.removeClass().addClass('mobile-320'); }
```